# Roots of cubic characteristic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need to find roots of this characteristic equation:
$$x^3-x^2(w+a+b)+x(bw+ba-b+a+w)-(bw-b+a) = 0,$$
where $a$, $b$ and $w$ are fixed but arbitrary integers. I tried online software but all in vain.

Comment: Could you please edit the formula using Jax?

Comment: Let each root be denoted $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$. Then use Vieta's formulae for a cubic. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: @AhmedBilal: Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha were able to find the three roots in terms of your variables. Of course the result looks ugly. For example, [*Wolfram Alpha result*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3-x%5E2(w%2Ba%2Bb)%2Bx(b+w%2Bb+a-b%2Ba%2Bw)-(b+w-b%2Ba)+%3D+0,+for+x).

Answer (score 1):

There is [Cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) for the general cubic, but it won't make you happy in general; it's a bit unwieldy. See the linked page for the general procedure, which has been known since the 16th century..